# css problems with clear both - big gap

Tags: html, css, css-float

HTML

```
 <div id="site-content">
                <div class="site-content">
                    <div id="site-content-left">
                    <h1>ՆՈՐ ԿԱՌՈՒՑՎՈՂ ԴՊՐՈՑԱՇԵՆՔ</h1>
                    <div id="site-content-dproc">
                        <div id="slider">
                            <div class="slide-img">img</div>
                            <div class="slide-text">
                                Consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="slide-read-more">
                                <a href="/arm/dprocashinutyun">Ավելին...</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div id="site-content-right">
                    <div id="embeddedExample" style="">
                        <div id="embeddedCalendar" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div id="site-content-ushadrutyun">
                <?php
                while($result_ushadrutyun_main_arm = mysql_fetch_array($query_main_ushadrutyun_arm)){
                    print $result_ushadrutyun_main_arm['short_content'];
                }
                ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                big gap
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#site-content{
    background:red;
    margin-left:250px;
}
.site-content {
width:740px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:25px 0 0 0;
}
#site-content-left{float:left;background:orange;}
#site-content-right{margin:5px 0 5px 10px;float:left;background:blue;}
#site-content-left h1{margin:0;font-family:erevan;font-size:25px;color:#0463a7;}
#site-content-dproc {background:url('../images/site-dproc.png');width:490px;height:370px;padding:10px;}
#site-content-dproc:hover{background:url('../images/site-dproc-hover.png');}
#site-content-news{float:left;}
#site-content-social{float:left;}
#site-content-news  .site-news-grey {background:url('../images/site-news-background.png') no-repeat;width:270px;height:182px;float:left;padding:25px;margin:0 10px 10px 0;display: inline-block}
#site-content-social #social-twitter{background:url('../images/social-twitter.png') no-repeat;width:70px;height:70px;margin-bottom:5px;display:block;}
#site-content-social #social-youtube{background:url('../images/social-youtube.png') no-repeat;width:70px;height:69px;margin-bottom:5px;display:block;}
#site-content-social #social-facebook{background:url('../images/social-facebook.png') no-repeat;width:70px;height:72px;margin-bottom:5px;display:block;}
#site-content-social #social-google{background:url('../images/social-google.png') no-repeat;width:70px;height:70px;margin-bottom:5px;display:block;}
#site-content-social #social-dasaran{background:url('../images/social-dasaran.png') no-repeat;width:70px;height:262px;margin-bottom:5px;display:block;}
#site-content-grey-news{width:670px;}
#site-content-ushadrutyun{
    background:url('../images/content-ushadrutyun.png') no-repeat;
    width:198px;
    height:123px;
    padding:10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:erevan;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#0463a7;
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
}



#site-content-ushadrutyun p {margin:0;}
#aaa {background:url('../images/news-calq.png') no-repeat;width:139px;height:78px;position:relative;top:-50px;}
#site-content-news h1 {margin:15px 0;font-family:erevan;font-size:25px;color:#0463a7;text-align:center;}
#corner-calq a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:erevan;
    color:#0463a7;
}
#corner-calq div {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-30deg); 
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }
#corner-calq a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}


.slide-img {float:left;margin-right:10px;}
.slide-text {text-align:justify;font-size:15px;}
.slide-text {height:250px;word-wrap:break-word;}
.slide-read-more {float:right;}
.slide-read-more  a{    margin:80px 0 0 30px;-moz-transform: rotate(-30deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-30deg); 
    transform: rotate(-30deg);}
```

after  is big gap with size near 300px. Any solution?

Comment: php routine won't help much :), can you produce a jsfiddle or codepen so it is easy to see . (position:relative could be a clue to reduce effect of clear)

Comment: I see whats the problem.. The thing is in menu. The gap height is big as menu div height. but still dont know how to solve

Comment: possible duplicate of [css - big gap after clear both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761723/css-big-gap-after-clear-both)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot add css attribute for the clear class

```
.clear {clear:both }
```