# css - big gap after clear both

Tags: html, css, css-float

Got problem with divs..

HTML

```
<div id="site-menu">menu1
    <br>menu2
    <br>menu3
    <br>menu4
    <br>menu5
    <br>menu6
    <br>
</div>
<div id="site-content">
    <div class="site-content">
        <div id="site-content-left">left</div>
        <div id="site-content-right">right</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.site-content {
    background:pink;
}
#site-content {
    background:red;
    margin-left:250px;
}
#site-content-left {
    background:orange;
    float:left;
}
#site-content-right {
    margin:5px 0 5px 0;
    background:blue;
}
#site-menu {
    float:left;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:grey;
}
.clear {
    clear:both
}
```

There is gap after clear both. The gap is big as menu div height (there is something with menu div).. Any solution please?

[jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6CCP8/)

Comment: it will be helpful if you will create some jsFiddle page with your code, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6CCP8/

Comment: a fiddle or bin would help a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [css problems with clear both - big gap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761293/css-problems-with-clear-both-big-gap)

Comment: try this 
.clear {
    clear: right;
}

Comment: Well, why are you using clear both. the only thing it does is cause you a problem.

Comment: @Fags if you add `clear:right;` then you might as well just remove it full stop, because it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots?  Instead of creating new question, rather edit to give clear picture of your problem.

Comment: http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/9162/o1ov.png - Here is the image

Comment: The space on the left side of "big gap" is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two way you can avoid big gap..

1) Instead of clear:both use clear:right
OR
2) Define proper floats for parent and sub divs instead of using margin. Proper div structure won't give above gap..

below is the style for each divs.

```
.site-content{background:pink; width:100%; float:left}
#site-content{
    background:red;
    margin-left:250px; 
}
#site-content-left{background:orange;float:left; width:5%; }
#site-content-right{margin:5px 0 5px 0;background:blue; float:right; display:block; width:95%}
#site-menu{
    float:left;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:grey;
}
.clear {clear:both}
```

Comment: float wont work in my case. Cause i dont want div with fixed width

Answer (score 0):

`clear:both` makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.

Remove `margin: left` from `#site-content`

```
#site-content{
    background:red;
}
```

check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HC69v/1/)